# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - May 3, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Thursday, May 3, 2018, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Thursday, May 3, 2018, 22:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/248747387/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on May 3rd, at 6:30 pm, at Roam in Buckhead!

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served. The full agenda is currently being worked on, so please check back for updates soon.

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 7:00 PM: Food, drinks, and social time
- 7:00 - 7:35 PM: [Craig Taylor](https://twitter.com/craigtfromatl) ([Avanade](https://www.avanade.com/en-us)) - Sitecore Commerce 9
- 7:35 - 8:10 PM: [Taylour Schneider](https://twitter.com/TaylourS_SC) ([Arke](https://www.arke.com/)) - Engagement Value Scores
- 8:10 - 8:30 PM: [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) and [George Chang](https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge) ([Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/)) - SUGCON Europe 2018 Recap
- 8:30 PM: End of event

### Presentations

#### Sitecore Commerce 9

**Speaker:** [Craig Taylor](https://twitter.com/craigtfromatl) - [Avanade](https://www.avanade.com/en-us)

- What's new with Commerce 9
- What you get out of the box
- Exploring the Commerce SDK
- Demonstrating the Commerce Habitat Sample Site
- Basic overview of integrating Commerce 9 with an external ecomm system

#### Engagement Value Scores

**Speaker:** [Taylour Schneider](https://twitter.com/TaylourS_SC) - [Arke](https://www.arke.com/)

How to think through engagement value scores and tying those back to the goals of a marketing organization.

#### SUGCON Europe 2018 Recap

**Speakers**: [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) and [George Chang](https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge) - [Perficient](https://www.perficient.com/)

A quick recap of the highlights and announcements from [SUGCON Europe 2018](http://www.sugcon.eu/) in Berlin.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Apr 23 at 22:30